# How to get the rank list of multiple number in a sublist and populate it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a TeamSquad made of players and each have tests store in a table.
Test results are stored in fields (int) such as RF1 and LF1. (right foot and Left Foot).
The data for the RF1 and LF1 has been populated on a prior date. For each player.  But I may not have a result in RF1 or LF1 for a player yet.

```
List< TeamSquadViewModel > teamsquad = new List< TeamSquadViewModel >();  

foreach (var item in teamsquadlist)
{
    TeamSquadViewModel data = new TeamSquadViewModel();
    data.Player = item;
    data.IsSelected = false;
    data.UserId = item.UserId;
                
    if (_testRepository.GetAllTestsForAPlayer(userlogged.User_Club_id, item.UserId).Any())
    {
        data.StatExists = true;
        data.LastTests = _testRepository.GetAllTestsForAPlayer(userlogged.User_Club_id, item.UserId).OrderByDescending(e => e.Test_Date_Record).FirstOrDefault();
                 
    }
    teamsquad.Add(data);
}
```

```
public class TeamSquadViewModel   {  

    public Player Player { get; set; }  
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }  
    public string UserId { get; set; }  
    public bool StatExists { get; set; }  
    //STATS AREA  
    public Test LastTests { get; internal set; }  
}
  
public class Test : BaseModel  
{  
    [Required]  
    public int Test_RF1  
    {  
        get  
        {  
            return GetValue<int>();  
        }  
        set  
        {  
            SetValue(value);  
        }  
    }  

    [Required]
    public int Test_LF1
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValue<int>();
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(value);
        }
    }
}
```

For each player, I have a

```
TeamSquadViewModel data = new TeamSquadViewModel();
```

Test_RF1 and TestRF1 and results of a test at a certain date. So I want to have a ranking on the last tests results for each player.
So how do I get the ranking of `Test_RF1`, `Test_LF1` and store it (I think I need 2 properties in my viewmodel) knowing that:
Some players may have the same results. I may not have the results yet from a player. (I'm ok we consider it to be 0).

Here an example:

| Rank | Score | Player |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 44 | Martin Dow |
| 2 | 42 | Jason Doe |
| 2 | 42 | Big Doe |
| 4 | 41 | Gary Doe |
| 4 | 41 | Bernard Doe |
| 4 | 41 | Barry Doe |
| 7 | 39 | Stephen Doe |
| 8 | 0 | John Doe |

Comment: Not the solution but I noted: you are using GetAllTestsForAPlayer unefficiently twice. Call it just once, store result in a variable then call Any and OrderBy on that variable.

Comment: Otherwise your question is fully unclear. What are rf1 and lf1? How the "example" relates to code you added to question? LastTests contains only the latest single test...

Comment: RF1 and LF! are results of a test on a certain date.  I only want the ranking of the last test for each players. Also, thank you for the inefficiently code call - Very much appreciated !

Comment: Martin would have for ex  RF1=44 ; Jason and Big : 42 RF1 so on and John has no record yet

Comment: I think the chances of getting suggestions will increase if you edit your question to add an example of specific input data that should result in your already provided output data.

Comment: @AstridE.
The Input data would be for Player Martin:
Date 1/1/2020 - RF1 = 40;
Date 1/3/2020 - RF1 = 42;
Date 1/4/2021 - RF1 = 44;
for Player Jason:
Date 1/1/2020 - RF1 = 38;
Date 1/3/2020 - RF1 = 42;
Date 1/4/2021 - RF1 = 42;